# Element UI dialog component can open for the first time, but it can't open for the second time

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, element-ui

I'm building web app with Vue, Nuxt, and Element UI.
I have a problem with the Element dialog component.
It can open for the first time, but it can't open for the second time.

This is the GIF about my problem.

https://gyazo.com/dfca3db76c75dceddccade632feb808f

This is my code.

- index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-button type="text" @click="handleDialogVisible">click to open the Dialog</el-button>
    <modal-first :visible=visible></modal-first>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import ModalFirst from './../components/ModalFirst.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    'modal-first': ModalFirst
  },
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleDialogVisible() {
      this.visible = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

- ModalFirst.vue

```
<template>
  <el-dialog
    title="Tips"
    :visible.sync="visible"
    width="30%"
  >
    <span>This is a message</span>
    <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
      <a>Hello</a>
    </span>
  </el-dialog>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: [ 'visible' ]
  }
</script>
```

And I can see a warning message on google chrome console after closing the dialog.
The warning message is below.

```
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "visible"

found in

---> <ModalFirst> at components/ModalFirst.vue
       <Pages/index.vue> at pages/index.vue
         <Nuxt>
           <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
             <Root>
```

This is the screenshot of the warning message.

https://gyazo.com/83c5f7c5a8e4d6816c35b3116c80db0d

Answer (score 0):

In vue , using directly to prop value is not allowed . Especially when your child component will update that prop value , in my option if prop will be use 
for display only using directly is not a problem .

In your code , `.sync` will update syncronously update data so I recommend to create local data.

ModalFirst.vue

```
<el-dialog
title="Tips"
:visible.sync="localVisible"
width="30%"
>
<script>
  export default {
    props: [ 'visible' ],
    data: function () {
       return {
          localVisible: this.visible // create local data using prop value
       }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. I think localVisible is not changed to true from false but visible props is changed from false to true.

Please see the following gif.
https://gyazo.com/2a59709ed3bfd72c7fa9da00ae87cd78

How can I fix it?

Comment: You won't be able to update the prop value, as props cannot be set in a child component. One way to go around it is to use `@input` to pass the updated value back to the parent component and have your parent component update the `visible` data variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the parent `visible` property to be updated, you can create your component to leverage `v-model`:

ModalFirst.vue

```
<el-dialog
title="Tips"
:visible.sync="localVisible"
width="30%"
>
<script>
  export default {
    props: [ 'value' ],
    data() {
       return {
          localVisible: null
       }
    },
    created() {
        this.localVisible = this.value;
        this.$watch('localVisible', (value, oldValue) => {
            if(value !== oldValue) { // Optional
                this.$emit('input', value); // Required
            }
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-button type="text" @click="handleDialogVisible">click to open the Dialog</el-button>
    <modal-first v-model="visible"></modal-first>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import ModalFirst from './../components/ModalFirst.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    'modal-first': ModalFirst
  },
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleDialogVisible() {
      this.visible = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

> `v-model` is basically a shorthand for `:value` and `@input`
>
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage

*Side-note*:

You can also import your component like so:

```
components: { ModalFirst },
```

as `ModalFirst` will be interpreted as `modal-first` as well by Vue.js